# fscanf doesn't find a word that starts with s

Tags: c

I have a very strange behavior with fgets:

```
FILE *config;
config = fopen("config.txt", "r");

int health, weapon, speed;
char search[50];

while (fgets(search ,sizeof(search), config) != NULL)
{
    fscanf(config, "health: %d", &health); 
    fscanf(config, "weapon: %d", &current_weapon); 
    fscanf(config, "speed: %d", &speed); 
}

fclose(config);
printf("%i", speed); //prints 0
```

config.txt:

```
health: 350
weapon: 1
speed: 20
```

If I change

```
fscanf(config, "speed: %d", &speed);
```

with

```
fscanf(config, "wordThatDoesntStartWithS: %d", &speed);
```

it works well.
Why?

Comment: I don't understand why you have the scanfs in a loop with fgets also.

Comment: What is `cerca`? Where is it declared?

Comment: I fixed the little problems in your example (wrong variable names) and it works for me with "speed" and DOES NOT with "wordThatDoesntStartWithS"

Comment: The `fgets()/sscanf()` fixes the overall problem as answered below.  OP's problem stems from improper use of mixing `fgets() and fscanf()`.  Rather than explain how to use 2 together, it is just better _not_ to use these 2 together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is super-strange.

The point of the `fgets()` is to read in a whole line of text. Then you *don't* need to use `fscanf()`, which reads from a stream: you've already read a line. Process the line you just read instead, using `sscanf()`.

Also, you need to check if `sscanf()` succeeds, and (of course) you can't expect to scan all three different things from the same line:

```
char line[1024];

bool got_speed = false, got_health = false, got_weapon = false;
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, config) != NULL)
{
  if(!got_speed && sscanf(line, "speed: %d", &speed) == 1)
    got_speed = true;
  if(!got_health && sscanf(line, "health: %d", &health) == 1)
    got_health = true;
  if(!got_weapon && sscanf(line, "weapon: %d", &weapon) == 1)
    got_weapon = true;
}
```

The above can be refactored to assign the right-hand side of the `&&` to the appropriate `got_`-flag, too.